# If from (1, $\alpha$) two tangents are drawn on exactly one branch of the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{4} -\frac{y^2}{1} = 1$ the alpha belongs to

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

> If from (1, $\alpha$) two tangents are drawn on exactly one branch of the hyperbola $$\frac{x^2}{4}  -\frac{y^2}{1} = 1$$ the alpha belongs to

[image]

As far as I can see two tangents can be drawn to only one branch if the point lies inside the branch opposite to it (the white area which is technically the outside but it looks inside ).

(1, alpha) lies in the blue region so we should be able to draw 2 tangents to both of the branches.

If it helps the range of alpha is given as $( -1/2, 1/2)$

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=two+tangents+are+drawn+on+exactly+one+branch+of+the+hyperbola&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN820IN820&oq=two+tangents+are+drawn+on+exactly+one+branch+of+the+hyperbola&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I did google ..

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) links to advice about asking questions, and about getting yourself unstuck. (Just friendly advice for any future questions) :)

Comment: Don't rely on "as far as eye can see". Sometimes seeing is just believing. You should have tried computing the tangent at all points on the hyperbola, rather than just using your eyeball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tangent to any hyperbola is of the form $y = mx ± \sqrt{a^2m^2 - b^2}$. Here, it will be of the form, $y = mx ± \sqrt{4m^2 - 1}$. 
Squaring both sides we get a quadratic equation,

$m^2(x^2 - 4) - (2xy)m + y^2 + 1 = 0$

The equation must have exactly two roots, $D>0$. Substitute $x=1$ and find the inequality for $y$.
This works because from that point you can draw tangents to only one branch.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With $$y=mx+n$$ and $$P(1,\alpha)$$ we get
$$\frac{x^2}{4}-(m(x-1)+\alpha)^2=1$$
Solve this equation for $x$